# Are all the uncountable infinite always greater than countable infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I read on an article about there are more reals than rationals because reals are uncountable. Here are my questions:

Are there more complex numbers than real numbers?
Are all the uncountable infinite always greater than countable infinite?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "more".   Mostly we use Cantor's.

There *does not* exist an injective function which maps real numbers one-to-one into rational numbers.   So we say $\Bbb R$ has *greater cardinality* than $\Bbb Q$.

There *does* exist a *bijective* function which maps complex numbers onto real numbers.   So we say $\Bbb C$ has *equal cardinality* to $\Bbb R$.   They have the cardinality of the continuum.

Although , there do exist sets with greater cardinality than the continuum.   The powerset fir the reals, for instance.

Comment: But how do we know R has greater cardinality than Q and not the other way around?

Comment: Cantor's diagonal argument shows that the reals are more numerous than the naturals.  We can construct a bijection between Q and N, so they are equinumerous.

Comment: @abc...  Be cause we *can* inject $\Bbb Q$ one-to-one into $\Bbb R$ , trivially, since $\forall q\in \Bbb Q\exists! r\in \Bbb R: r=q$.

Comment: Uncountable infinite what?  An uncountable infinite ordinal number?